# Material UI Switch no UI change

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom, uiswitch

I'm using Material UI's switch to change themes on a multi-page app. The only bug that happens is the switch does not move from left to right (ui functionality does not occur), but the onChange functionality is working fine. I played around with it, turns out that when I remove forceUpdate(), the material ui switch will work, but the component will not be rerendered. What in forceUpdate is preventing the switch functionality from working?

App.tsx :

```
import React from "react"
import {Switch, Route, BrowserRouter, Redirect} from "react-router-dom"
import Main from "./Main"
import {createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider} from "@material-ui/core";

class App extends React.Component<any, any>{

darkmode=true

theme=createMuiTheme({
    palette:{
        type:this.darkmode?"dark" : "light"

    },
})

changeTheme=()=>{
    this.darkmode=!this.darkmode;
   
    this.theme = createMuiTheme({
        palette:{
            type:this.darkmode?"dark" : "light"
        }
    })
    this.theme.spacing(10)
    this.forceUpdate()
}


render(){
    return(
       
   
           <div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route  path="/" component={()=>
                            <Main theme={this.theme} changeTheme={this.changeTheme} />
                        }
                                                    
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>

           </div>

       

    )
}
```

}

Main.tsx:

```
class Main extends React.Component<any,any>{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Switch onChange={()=>this.props.changeTheme()}></Switch>
                <Switch></Switch>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't use states the UI will not rerender if you don't pass a new state

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {darkmode: true};
  }
this.setState({
      darkmode: !darkmode
    });
```

the two piece of code here will help you the first one in the initialize of the state
and the second is the update

> By default, when your component’s state or props change, your component will re-render. If your render() method depends on some other data, you can tell React that the component needs re-rendering by calling forceUpdate().

take from [react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) that explain
what it's do basically it's rernder by force the component you should avoid to all use and make the read from the props and state